# fontawesome 5 could not find one or more icon in vue js application

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome-5

I get error when Im using Font Awesome 5 icon in Vue Js application:

**Error**

**Could not find one or more icon(s)**

This is my package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.9",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.6.0",
"@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
"vue": "^2.5.17",
"vue-router": "^3.0.2"
},
```

**And this is my main.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './Main.vue'
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(Bootstrap);

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faCoffee);
Vue.component('icon', FontAwesomeIcon);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

**I am using fontawesome like this:**

```
<icon :icon="['fas', 'user']" />
```

**But i get error in console**

Answer (score 1):

The icon for user has not been imported, but the one for coffee has been instead.

You need to use:

```
import { faUser } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

Then, add the imported font to the library as follows:

```
library.add(faUser);
```

Then use the font in your component:

```
<icon :icon="['fas', 'user']" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Much easier why to do that is just `<icon icon='coffee'>`

If you are trying `<icon :icon="['fas', 'user']" />` - you didn't imported 'user' icon. That error generally means you are trying to use icon that was not imported, so can be misspell for example.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem but accidentally found the solution.

As I had also discovered, the usual method did not work in some cases. For instance, I was looking for the `fa-location-dot` icon, and the same thing happened to me.

So, as the below image shows, at the bottom left corner of [Font Awesome's icon detail modal](https://fontawesome.com/icons/location-dot?f=classic&s=solid), there is a `Aliases: map-marker-alt` (for this case).

[Fonta Awesome Icon selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYB6w.png)

So, I tried importing it into my Vue file, and instead of this...

```
import { faLocationDot } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
library.add(faLocationDot);
```

...and ended up solving it with the - almost - provided alias, with just a minor modification:

```
import { faMapMarkerAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
library.add(faMapMarkerAlt);
```